# Angular 4+ bootstrap NgbAccordion how to expand / collapse all

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I've been playing around with angular in combination with ng-bootstrap and I am stumped about the following:

I have this NgbAccordion on my page:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
    <ngb-panel *ngFor="let container of answer.resultObj.containers.containers" title="{{container.metadata.title}}">
      <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
        <app-containers [container]="container"></app-containers>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
  </ngb-accordion>
```

this results in a lit of ngb-panels all collapsed. This is precisely what I want and I can toggle the expansion of the app-container objects by clicking on them.

***I also want a button to expand all the ngb-panels***. I can't seem to get it to work. I found a nice example based on Angularjs (<2) but that does not work and the [isOpen] option that seemed to have been there at one time does not exist anymore?!

My angular component:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Answer} from '../model/answer';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-answer',
  templateUrl: './answer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./answer.component.css'],
  providers: []
})
export class AnswerComponent {
  @Input() answer: Answer;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Could anyone help me with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68889114/how-to-change-activeids-of-ngb-accordion-based-on-the-button-we-click-in-angular

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `activeIds` input on the accordion

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api

Basically, assign a unique id to each of your panels

```
<ngb-panel *ngFor="let container ...; let i= index" title="Panel{{i}}" id="panel-{{i}}"
```

and declare in your component a list of the active ids (= ids of the panels that must be open)

```
activeIds: string[] = [];
```

Then modify that list when you want to open/close the panels

```
this.activeIds = [];//All panels closed
this.activeIds = ['panel-1', 'panel-2']; //panels 1 and 2 are open
```

And bind this variable to the `activeIds` input of the accordion

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" [activeIds]="activeIds"
```

Finally, add the buttons

```
<button (click)="activeIds=[]" >close all</button>
<button (click)="openAll()" >open all</button>

openAll()
{
    this.activeIds = [/* add all panel ids here */];
}
```

I created a stackblitz to illustrate this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzzwnc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That will work I think but IMHO a lot of work as I first have to dynamically re-create the id's I'm going to use from my dynamic input list of items to show in panels.

Comment: It's just a one liner, like in my example (using map), isn't it?

Comment: Not quite It might be trouble generating the Id's as I use the component more than once on the same screen and the input 'might' have the same data in it. But essentially I will figure this out based on your explanation and great example :-)

Comment: Important: it should be id="{{...}} and not [attr.id]="..." or it will not work properly.

Answer (score 2):

= Here is a solution that will allow you to open only one accordion at a time.
you can use with (panelChange) Captures changes of ngb like this:

html:

```
   <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion"  [activeIds]="activeId"  (panelChange)="toggleAccordian($event)">
    <ngb-panel *ngFor="let option of options;" title="{{option}}">
        <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                      <!--some code-->
                    </ul>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

ts:

```
activeId: string = "";

toggleAccordian(event) {
    // If it is already open you will close it and if it is closed open it
    this.activeId = this.activeId == event.panelId ? "" : event.panelId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current [ng-bootstrap docu of 11.0.0](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples#header) shows expandAll/collapseAll as basic component example and their solution is pretty straight forward:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm ml-2" (click)="acc.collapseAll()">Collapse all</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm ml-2" (click)="acc.expandAll()">Expand all</button>
<br>
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
    <!-- your accordion: ngb-panel, ng-template, etc.. -->
</ngb-accordion>
```

*In the docu the button [Collapse All] is part of a ngb-Panel - but you can simply move that code out of the ngb-accordion like showcased above.*