# how to change activeIds of ngb Accordion based on the button we click in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm implementing the ngbAccordion in a modal in another component. When I click on a button1 ,my modal with the accordian should popup, with "Acc1" tab open , similarly with button 2.

Could anyone help me. please find my code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-6r9hfp-k7upwx?file=src%2Fapp%2FaccordionInModal%2Facc-in-modal.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer updated: Just used @Input directive for panelId .  Please find it here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-6r9hfp-k7upwx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts